# Python Script for Art Museum Installation intermittently locks up, Removing Thermal Camera Sensor read function seems to work?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, raspberry-pi3, led

I have a python script for an installation in an art museum that is meant to run continuously playing sounds, driving an LED matrix, and sensing people via OpennCV and a thermal camera.

Each of the parts of the script work and all of them work together but randomly the script locks up and I need to restart it.  I want to script to not lock up so no one has to reset it during the exhibition.

I have the code running on a spare Raspberry Pi and a spare LED matrix and it continues to cycle through fine.  The only changes that I made were commenting out the start of a thread to check the IR sensor and a call to a function to get the max temp from the sensor.

To be clear, if I leave these bits of code in the script runs fine 1 -3 or sometimes 10 times.  But it seems to lock up in the first "state" when `IRcount = 0`

I am stuck.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

````
```
#!/usr/bin/python
import glob
import queue
import sys
import pygame
import cv2
import random
import math
import colorsys
import time
from rpi_ws281x import *
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import threading
global thresh

sys.path.insert(0, "/home/pi/irpython/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.5")
import MLX90640 as mlx

currentTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
minTime = 6000
maxTime = 12000
lineHeight1 = 0
lineHue1 = float(random.randrange(1,360))/255

# IR Functions

# Function to just grab the Max Temp detected. If over threshold then start
# the sequence, if not stay in state 0
def maxTemp():
  mlx.setup(8) #set frame rate of MLX90640

  f = mlx.get_frame()

  mlx.cleanup()

  # get max and min temps from sensor
  # v_min = min(f)
  v_max = int(max(f))
  return v_max

# Function to detect individual people's heat blob group of pixels
# run in a thread only at the end of the script
def irCounter():
    img = Image.new( 'L', (24,32), "black") # make IR image

    mlx.setup(8) #set frame rate of MLX90640

    f = mlx.get_frame()

    mlx.cleanup()

    for x in range(24):
        row = []
        for y in range(32):
            val = f[32 * (23-x) + y]
            row.append(val)
            img.putpixel((x, y), (int(val)))

    # convert raw temp data to numpy array
    imgIR = np.array(img)

    # increase the 24x32 px image to 240x320px for ease of seeing
    bigIR = cv2.resize(depth_uint8, dsize=(240,320), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    # Use a bilateral filter to blur while hopefully retaining edges
    brightBlurIR = cv2.bilateralFilter(bigIR,9,150,150)

    # Threshold the image to black and white 
    retval, threshIR = cv2.threshold(brightBlurIR, 26, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # Define kernal for erosion and dilation and closing operations
    kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

    erosionIR = cv2.erode(threshIR,kernel,iterations = 1)

    dilationIR = cv2.dilate(erosionIR,kernel,iterations = 1)

    closingIR = cv2.morphologyEx(dilationIR, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    # Detect countours
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closingIR, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    # Get the number of contours ( contours count when touching edge of image while blobs don't)
    ncontours = str(len(contours))

    # Show images in window during testing
    cv2.imshow("Combined", closingIR)

    cv2.waitKey(1)

#initialize pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(30)
print("pygame initialized")

# assign sound chennels for pygame
channel0 = pygame.mixer.Channel(0)
channel1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
channel2 = pygame.mixer.Channel(2)
channel3 = pygame.mixer.Channel(3)
channel4 = pygame.mixer.Channel(4)
channel5 = pygame.mixer.Channel(5)
channel6 = pygame.mixer.Channel(6)
channel7 = pygame.mixer.Channel(7)
channel8 = pygame.mixer.Channel(8)
channel9 = pygame.mixer.Channel(9)
channel10 = pygame.mixer.Channel(10)
channel11 = pygame.mixer.Channel(11)
channel12 = pygame.mixer.Channel(12)
channel13 = pygame.mixer.Channel(13)
channel14 = pygame.mixer.Channel(14)
channel15 = pygame.mixer.Channel(15)
channel16 = pygame.mixer.Channel(16)
channel17 = pygame.mixer.Channel(17)
channel18 = pygame.mixer.Channel(18)
channel19 = pygame.mixer.Channel(19)
channel20 = pygame.mixer.Channel(20)
channel21 = pygame.mixer.Channel(21)
channel22 = pygame.mixer.Channel(22)
channel23 = pygame.mixer.Channel(23)
channel24 = pygame.mixer.Channel(24)
channel25 = pygame.mixer.Channel(25)
channel26 = pygame.mixer.Channel(26)
channel27 = pygame.mixer.Channel(27)
channel28 = pygame.mixer.Channel(28)


# load soundfiles
echoballs = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/echo balls FIX.ogg")
organbounce = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/ORGAN BOUNCE fix.ogg")
jar = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/jar whoop fix.ogg")
garland = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/GARLAND_fix.ogg")
dribble= pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/dribble.ogg")
cowbell = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/cowbell fix.ogg")
clackyballs = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/clacky balls boucne.ogg")
burpees = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/burpees_fix.ogg")
brokensynth = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/broken synth bounce.ogg")
woolballs = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/wool balls in jar FIX.ogg")
wiimoye = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/wiimoye_fix.ogg")
warpyorgan = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/warpy organ bounce#.2.ogg")
vibrate = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/vibrate fix.ogg")
turtlesbounce = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/turtles fix.ogg")
timer = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/timer.ogg")
tape = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/tape fix.ogg")
tambourine = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/TAMBOURINE.ogg")
springybounce = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/springy bounce.ogg")
smash3 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/smash fix.ogg")
bristle2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/BRISTLE FIX.ogg")
blackkeys = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/black keys FIX.ogg")
zipper = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/zipper.ogg")

presatisfactionsweep = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/pre-satisfaction sweep .ogg")
satisfaction = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/SATISFACTION.ogg")
altsatisfaction = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/alt_satisfaction_trimmed.ogg")
solosatisfaction = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/SOLO_SATISFACTION.ogg")
print("sound files loaded")

# initializing sounds list  
soundsList = [echoballs, organbounce, zipper, jar, garland, dribble, cowbell, clackyballs, burpees, brokensynth, woolballs,
       wiimoye, warpyorgan, vibrate, turtlesbounce, timer, tambourine, springybounce, smash3, bristle2, blackkeys, zipper       ] 

IRcount = 0 # define initial state for main loop
pygame.display.set_mode((32, 8))
print("pygame dispaly open")

# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT      = 256      # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN        = 18      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (18 uses PWM!).
#LED_PIN        = 10     # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (10 uses SPI /dev/spidev0.0).
LED_FREQ_HZ    = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA        = 10      # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 10)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 100     # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT     = False   # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)
LED_CHANNEL    = 0       # set to '1' for GPIOs 13, 19, 41, 45 or 53

# Define functions which animate LEDs in various ways.

# PNG to LED function used to shuffle througfh folders of numbered PNGs exported
# from animations created
def pngToLED (strip, pngfile):
    RGBimage = Image.open(pngfile).convert('RGB')
    np_image = np.array(RGBimage)
    colours = [Color(x[0],x[1],x[2]) for rows in np_image for x in rows]
    colours2d = np.reshape(colours, (32, 8), order='F')
    colours2d[1::2, :] = colours2d[1::2, ::-1]
    pic = colours2d.flatten('C')
    for i in range( 0, strip.numPixels(), 1 ):# iterate over all LEDs - range(start_value, end_value, step)
        strip.setPixelColor(i, int(pic[ i ]))
    strip.show()

def colorWipe(strip, color,wait_ms=10):
    """Wipe color across display a pixel at a time."""
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
    strip.show()
    time.sleep(1)

def theaterChase(strip, color, wait_ms, iterations=10):
    """Movie theater light style chaser animation."""
    for j in range(iterations):
        for q in range(3):
            for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                strip.setPixelColor(i+q, color)
            strip.show()
            time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)
            for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0)

def wheel(pos):
    """Generate rainbow colors across 0-255 positions."""
    if pos < 85:
        return Color(pos * 3, 255 - pos * 3, 0)
    elif pos < 170:
        pos -= 85
        return Color(255 - pos * 3, 0, pos * 3)
    else:
        pos -= 170
        return Color(0, pos * 3, 255 - pos * 3)

def rainbow(strip, wait_ms=20, iterations=1):
    """Draw rainbow that fades across all pixels at once."""
    for j in range(256*iterations):
        for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
            strip.setPixelColor(i, wheel((i+j) & 255))
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)

def rainbowCycle(strip, wait_ms=20, iterations=5):
    """Draw rainbow that uniformly distributes itself across all pixels."""  
    for j in range(256*iterations):

        for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
            strip.setPixelColor(i, wheel((int(i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255))
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)

def theaterChaseRainbow(strip, wait_ms=90):
    """Rainbow movie theater light style chaser animation."""
    for j in range(256):
        for q in range(3):
            for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                strip.setPixelColor(i+q, wheel((i+j) % 255))
            strip.show()
            time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)
            for i in range(0, strip.numPixels(), 3):
                strip.setPixelColor(i+q, 0)

# Plasma LED Function from Root 42
def plasmaLED (plasmaTime):
    h = 8
    w = 32
    out = [ Color( 0, 0, 0 ) for x in range( h * w ) ]
    plasmaBright = 100.0
    for x in range( h ):
        for y in range( w ):
            hue = (4.0 + math.sin( plasmaTime + x ) + math.sin( plasmaTime + y / 4.5 ) \
                + math.sin( x + y + plasmaTime ) + math.sin( math.sqrt( ( x + plasmaTime ) ** 2.0 + ( y + 1.5 * plasmaTime ) ** 2.0 ) / 4.0 ))/8
            hsv = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb( hue , 1, 1 )
            if y % 2 == 0: #even
                out[ x + (h * y)] = Color( *[ int( round( c * plasmaBright ) ) for c in hsv ] )
            else: #odd
                out[ (y * h) + (h -1 -x) ] = Color( *[ int( round( c * plasmaBright ) ) for c in hsv ] )
    for i in range( 0, strip.numPixels(), 1 ):# iterate over all LEDs - range(start_value, end_value, step)
        strip.setPixelColor(i, out[ i ]) # set pixel to color in picture
    strip.show()

# variables for plasma
plasmaTime = 5.0 # time
plasmaSpeed = 0.05 # speed of time

# thread for IRcounter function
class TempTask:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ir_temp = 0
        self.lock = threading.Lock() #control concurrent access for safe multi thread access
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.update_temp)

    def update_temp(self):
        while True:
            with self.lock:
                self.ir_temp = irCounter()
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

# Millis timer count function
def CheckTime( lastTime,  wait):
  if currentTime - lastTime >= wait:
    lastTime += wait
    return True
  return False


# Main program logic follows:
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # not currently starting the trhead because program is locking up without it
    # want to figure out initial problem first
    #start thread
    #task = TempTask()
    #task.start()

    # Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.
    strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL)
    # Intialize the library (must be called once before other functions).
    strip.begin()

    print ('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

    try:
        while True:
            currentTime = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

            if IRcount == 0:         

                #random solid color
                colorWipe(strip, Color(random.randint(60,255), random.randint(60,255), random.randint(60,255)))

                # use random.sample() to shuffle sounds list 
                shuffledSounds = random.sample(soundsList, len(soundsList))
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(0).get_busy() == False: channel0.play(shuffledSounds[0],loops = -1)
                thresh = 0
                '''
                # the threshold check below is the only thing I have taken out of
                # Program on my test Raspberry Pi.  It seems to not lock up without it
                # not sure why this would be a problem.

                thresh = int(maxTemp())
                print (thresh)
                if thresh >= 27:
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  print (thresh)
                  IRcount = 1
                  print("Threshold Temp Detected: Begin Sound Sequence")
                else:
                  IRcount = 0
                  '''
                if CheckTime(InflateWait,random.randint(minTime, maxTime)):
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  IRcount += 1
                  print(IRcount)

            elif IRcount == 1:
                LEDimages = glob.glob("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/Crystal_Mirror/*.png")
                for LEDimage in sorted(LEDimages):
                  pngToLED (strip, LEDimage)
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(1).get_busy() == False:
                  channel1.play(shuffledSounds[1],loops = -1)
                  waitTime = random.randint(minTime, maxTime)
                if CheckTime(InflateWait,waitTime):
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  IRcount += 1
                  print(IRcount)

            elif IRcount == 2:
                LEDimages = glob.glob("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/Mercury_Loop/*.png")
                for LEDimage in sorted(LEDimages):
                  pngToLED (strip, LEDimage)
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(2).get_busy() == False:
                  channel2.play(shuffledSounds[2],loops = -1)
                  waitTime = random.randint(minTime, maxTime)
                if CheckTime(InflateWait,waitTime):
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  IRcount += 1
                  print(IRcount)

            elif IRcount == 3:
                LEDimages = glob.glob("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/Pink_Lava/*.png")
                for LEDimage in sorted(LEDimages):
                  pngToLED (strip, LEDimage)            
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(3).get_busy() == False:
                  channel3.play(shuffledSounds[3],loops = -1)
                  waitTime = random.randint(minTime, maxTime)
                if CheckTime(InflateWait,waitTime):
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  IRcount += 1
                  print(IRcount)

            elif IRcount == 4:
                LEDimages = glob.glob("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/Horiz_Mosaic/*.png")
                for LEDimage in sorted(LEDimages):
                  pngToLED (strip, LEDimage)
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(4).get_busy() == False:
                  channel4.play(shuffledSounds[4],loops = -1)
                  waitTime = random.randint(minTime, maxTime)
                if CheckTime(InflateWait,waitTime):
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  IRcount += 1
                  print(IRcount)


            elif IRcount == 5:
                plasmaLED()
                plasmaTime = plasmaTime + plasmaSpeed  # increment plasma time
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(5).get_busy() == False:
                  channel5.play(shuffledSounds[5],loops = -1)
                  waitTime = random.randint(minTime, maxTime)
                if CheckTime(InflateWait,waitTime):
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  IRcount += 1
                  print(IRcount)


            elif IRcount == 6:
                LEDimages = glob.glob("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/Radio_Loop/*.png")
                for LEDimage in sorted(LEDimages):
                  pngToLED (strip, LEDimage)
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(6).get_busy() == False:
                  channel6.play(shuffledSounds[6],loops = -1)
                  waitTime = random.randint(minTime, maxTime)
                if CheckTime(InflateWait,waitTime):
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  IRcount += 1
                  print(IRcount)


            elif IRcount == 7:
                LEDimages = glob.glob("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/Star_Loop/*.png")
                for LEDimage in sorted(LEDimages):
                  pngToLED (strip, LEDimage)
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(7).get_busy() == False:
                  channel7.play(shuffledSounds[7],loops = -1)
                  waitTime = random.randint(minTime, maxTime)
                if CheckTime(InflateWait,waitTime):
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  IRcount += 1




            elif IRcount == 14:
                plasmaLED()
                plasmaTime = plasmaTime + plasmaSpeed  # increment plasma time
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(14).get_busy() == False:
                  channel14.play(shuffledSounds[14],loops = -1)
                  waitTime = random.randint(minTime, maxTime)
                if CheckTime(InflateWait,waitTime):
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  IRcount += 1
                  print(IRcount)
                  print (thresh)

            elif IRcount == 15:
                plasmaLED()
                plasmaTime = plasmaTime + plasmaSpeed  # increment plasma time
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(15).get_busy() == False:
                  channel15.play(shuffledSounds[15],loops = -1)
                  waitTime = random.randint(minTime, maxTime)
                if CheckTime(InflateWait,waitTime):
                  InflateWait = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
                  IRcount += 1
                  print(IRcount)




            elif IRcount == 16:
                # random color theater chase increment random ms to speed up with sounds
                theaterChase(strip, Color(random.randint(1,255), random.randint(1,255), random.randint(1,255)), random.randint(40,50))
                pygame.mixer.fadeout(45000)
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(22).get_busy() == False:
                  channel22.play(presatisfactionsweep)
                IRcount = 17
                print(IRcount)
                print("sweep end start")


            elif IRcount == 18:
                 # random color theater chase increment random ms to speed up with sounds
                theaterChase(strip, Color(random.randint(1,255), random.randint(1,255), random.randint(1,255)), random.randint(30,40))
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(22).get_busy() == False:
                    pygame.mixer.stop()
                    channel23.play(satisfaction)
                    IRcount = 19
                    print(IRcount)
                    print("Play Satisfaction Sount")

            elif IRcount == 19:
                rainbowCycle(strip, 5)
                if pygame.mixer.Channel(23).get_busy() == False: IRcount = 0

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
       colorWipe(strip, Color(0,0,0), 1)
       pygame.mixer.stop()
       pygame.quit()
```
````

**Update 1 - Suspected Function(s)**

When I left the script run overnight and came to the exhibit in the morning it would be stuck in the 1st state `IRcount = 0` The only things that happen in that state is the `maxTemp()` function to get the max temp, the LED color wipe function to cycle colors.

When I would come in in the morning it would be stuck, playing a single sound from pygame, as it should, but it would not be cycling colors.  I removed the `maxTemp()` from my test Pi and it has been working fine.

```
    def maxTemp():
          mlx.setup(8) #set frame rate of MLX90640

          f = mlx.get_frame()

          mlx.cleanup()

          # get max and min temps from sensor
          # v_min = min(f)
          v_max = int(max(f))
          return v_max
```

**Update # 2**

I thought that the thread might be the problem so I commented out the thread start call.  That is why I made the simpler `maxTemp()` function to see if that would work better than the thread.  So when I was using the max temp then the thread wasn't being called.

I don't understand threads very well.  Is it possible to have the max temp variable update continuously and have the simple OpenCV numPy manipulations running continuously?  That would be ideal.  When I originally added the thread it seemed to stop after a few cycles.

I do not have a join on the thread. I know threads don't "restart" but do I need to call it again as the state machine starts again?

```
    # not currently starting the thread because program is locking up without it
        # want to figure out initial problem first
        #start thread
        #task = TempTask()
        #task.start()
```

**Update #3**

I Uploaded new code that eliminated the duplicate functions.  Everything is handled in the thread `temp.task` now.  That seems to work fine.  I also put the github suggestion of polling the thermal sensor if the image is a duplicate but that has not happened.

I left the program run over night and when I came in in the morning it was locked up.  The SD card is set to read only mode.  I ssh'd into the pi. I have my auto start python script in `/etc/profile`
It seems to start the script each time I log into ssh.  When I logged in this morning to see if the pi was still up it game an out of memory error.

````
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ruff-wavs/shufflewavdemo.py", line 210, in <module>
    altsatisfaction = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/alt_satisfaction_trimmed.ogg")
pygame.error: Unable to open file '/home/pi/ruff-wavs/sounds/alt_satisfaction_trimmed.ogg'
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 223, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 145, in main
    output.close()
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
````

```
Could that be because it is in read only mode?

I used this script to switch from writable to read only and back.
[https://github.com/JasperE84/root-ro][1]


  [1]: https://github.com/JasperE84/root-ro
```

Comment: It's hard to test this without access to the hardware. You'll need to do some extra debugging. Which function is is getting stuck in? Put in some extra print and log the output so you can see where it's hanging. Check the kernel logs to see if there are any issues with the hardware (eg IR camera dropping off USB bus etc).

Comment: Thank you, yes without the hardware, hard for others, it is a MLX90640 Thermal Camera.  I am away from the exhibit for two days so can only test on my duplicate Pi until then. I come from an Arduino world, could it be something with the way I have my timers and pseudo state machine? I added an update in the original post to highlight and explain where I think it is hanging.  When I get to the exhibit, do I at a unique print line after each line of code in the suspected function?

Comment: Sounds like a cool installation. Best of luck with it.

Comment: Thanks.  I will continue to do testing on my spare Pi and then will try to implement your suggestions in a couple days when I have physical access to the hardware again.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that you're accessing the `mlx` device both in the main thread via `maxTemp()` as well as in the `irCounter()` thread. The fact that it works when you take out the `maxTemp` call, and that that call happens in the `if IRcount == 0:` state supports this.

I would add the `maxTemp` functionality to the `irCounter` thread, so that accessing it from only a single thread; and update a global variable (protected by a lock) with the maxTemp results if you need to retain this functionality.

Comment: The problem has to be with the sensor or with the way I am interacting with it, since my test program without it works fin with sound and LEDs.  I added an update #2 above to show that I already commented out the thread start call and it still didn't work.  I made the `maxTemp()` function to simplify things for debugging.  I like the idea of having everything in one thread.  Do I need to end the thread and start it up again as the pseudo state maching transitions from `IRcount  = 19` to `IRcount = 0` ?

Comment: @lukecv I wonder if it's the hardware interface to the sensor that is causing a problem. Take a look at this page which suggests that the smbus on the Pi 3 can hang https://github.com/leswright1977/mlx90640_python .

Comment: That is a very interesting Github readme.  It is based on the same library from Pimoroni that I am using.  The symptom of the I2c randomly hanging is exactly what is happening with my script. Although it appears that the whole script hangs when the i2C hangs. I will try the code changes when back at device in two days, and if they work make this question as complete, thank you for a promising lead.

Comment: I removed duplicate functions to eliminate possible sensor interference.  The script works fine during the day. I left it over night in read only SD card mode and came in with out of memory errors printing in the terminal when I logged in.  I put more details in Update #3 above.  Is there a way to avoid the out of memory error?  I have the script auto start from `/etc/profile` it seems to start with every ssh login.  Could that be the problem?  Is there a way to sump the memory in read only?

Comment: I would run it as a service by creating a systemd service file in /etc/systemd/system and then schedule a restart of the service overnight (or every few hours). Yes those errors look like it's due to read only file system. You may need to mount a tmp folder in ram disk and run it from there so you have somewhere for it to save files to disk

Comment: It looks like that GitHub script already creates an overlay filesystem so that all file writes are stored temporarily in a ramdisk. So your script is possibly just writing a lot of data to disk over time and filling up available ram. Could also be the log files